# After updating edmx model, what about DbContext?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008-r2, entity-framework-5, dbcontext

I just started using EF5. I created a MSSQL database, then I created the model (edmx) file and then used the "Add code generation item" to create EF5 `dbcontext` classes.

Whenever I alter my database (adding a column or changing a datatype) I see that "update model from database" doesn't work and I need to delete and recreate the model.
that's ok for me but what happens to my `DbContext` classes generated from the `model.tt` template file? do I have to generate all the `DbContext` classes again also?

what's the correct way to work with a database-first environment and keep the `.edmx` model and the `DbContext` classes in sync with the database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After you update your model from database, try to `Run Custom Tool` the Entity Model, works and tested for me.

from `Entity Model` → <kbd>Right Click</kbd> → <kbd>Run Custom Tool</kbd>

Comment: Actually, if I change the datatype of a field in SQL Server, updating the model won't update the property. I need to delete and re-add the table in order. Annoying

Answer (score 1):

I could see two ways of doing it:

1) Use EF4 approach (that should be possible with EF5 too) that is use edmx and database first flow. Then whenever you have changes in your database, you just "Update Your Model from Database.." from edmx designer context-menu. That automatically updates your generated entity classes.

2) Use EF5 approach - Generate your POCO classes one time, do not use edmx at all. You can do this by using Entity Framework Power Tools and then use "Reverse Engineer Code First". Apply manually changes to your classes when database model changes (that obviously would work only with incremental database changes).

Answer (score 0):

In VS2010 there is a button at the very right top of the solution explorer called "Transform all templates" which update your generated classes